# Convert ASCII character to x11 keycode

Tags: c, ascii, xll

I have a small program that takes input in the form of ascii characters. I need to be able to convert these to keycodes for use with x11 functions. Is there a xlib function to do this or another library? Or will a large switch case work best?

Comment: although this question is quite old, consider accepting @BobDoolittle's answer instead of mine

Comment: Since this question is old, it's probably good to mention that most input is not given in ASCII these days, and solutions for converting UTF to key codes are possible, though more complicated or slightly less standardized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XStringToKeysym`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XStringToKeysym.html) to convert at least alphanumeric characters to `KeySym`s, followed by [`XKeysymToKeycode`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/utilities/keyboard/XKeysymToKeycode.html) for conversion to `KeyCode`s:

```
Display *display = ...;
KeySym sym_a = XStringToKeysym("A");
KeyCode code_a = XKeysymToKeycode(display, sym_a);
```

---

As @BobDoolitle pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771958/591495), while `XStringToKeysym` works for alphanumeric single-character strings, it fails in the ASCII general case. He provides a way to trivially handle the majority of ASCII characters (`0x20`–`0x7F`) although characters outside that range require more careful treatment.

Comment: This doesn't work in the general case. XStringToKeysym maps KeySym names, not ASCII characters. You'll often be OK because for common printing characters the KeySym name matches the character, but it won't work for example for a space character.

Answer (score 14):

This question has an old, wrong answer (from @oldrinb), that oddly has never been challenged. As stated in the comment, you can't use XStringToKeysym to map chars to KeySyms in a general way. It will work for letters and numbers, but that's about it, because the KeySym name happens to map directly for those ASCII characters. For other ASCII characters such as punctuation or space it won't work.

But you can do better than that. If you look at `<X11/keysymdef.h>` you find that for `ASCII` 0x20-0xFF, the characters map *directly* to `XKeySyms`. So, I'd say it's simpler to just use that range of characters directly as `KeySyms`, and just map the remaining 32 characters to their corresponding `KeyCodes`. So I'd say the code should more properly be:

```
Display *display = ...;
if ((int)c >= 0x20) {
    XKeysymToKeycode(display, (KeySym)c);
} else {
    ... // Exercise left to the reader :-)
}
```

The 'else' clause will require multiple `KeyCodes` since for example `ASCII` 1 (Control-A) is `XK_A` with the `XK_CONTROL_R` (or `XK_CONTROL_L`) Modifier. So you'd have to issue for example: `XK_CONTROL_L` DOWN, `XK_A` DOWN, `XK_A` UP, `XK_CONTROL_L` UP.

Here's a toy program that demonstrates this by echoing the first argument via simulated keyboard events:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib-xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_event.h>
#include <xcb/xtest.h>

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *pc;
    xcb_connection_t *xconn;
    KeyCode code_a;
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    xconn = XGetXCBConnection(dpy);

    for (pc = argv[1]; *pc != '\0'; ++pc) {
        if (*pc >= (char)0x20) {
            code_a = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, (KeySym)*pc);
            xcb_test_fake_input(xconn, XCB_KEY_PRESS, code_a, XCB_CURRENT_TIME, XCB_NONE, 0, 0, 0);
            xcb_test_fake_input(xconn, XCB_KEY_RELEASE, code_a, XCB_CURRENT_TIME, XCB_NONE, 0, 0, 0);
            xcb_flush(xconn);
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "Eeek - out-of-range character 0x%x\n", (unsigned int)*pc);
        }
    }
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
}
```

You need to link it with: `-lX11 -lxcb -lxcb-xtest -lX11-xcb`

Disclaimer: No KeySyms were harmed in the writing of this code.

Comment: The answer to that depends on your business logic. There is no ASCII mapping in that case. What would you like your application to do when there is no mapping? You could ignore it, generate an error, ring a bell, or halt and catch fire. Whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: Nice disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do implement the mapping by hand too, from, say, the output of `xmodmap -pke` (but it would break on X11 installations that don't the same mapping). Something like this (for ASCII):

```
typedef struct{
    xcb_keycode_t code;
    u16           state;
}x11_key_t;

x11_key_t X11_ASCII_TO_KEY[] = {
    ['1'] ={10,0x0000}, ['!'] ={10,0x0001},
    ['2'] ={11,0x0000}, ['@'] ={11,0x0001},
    ['3'] ={12,0x0000}, ['#'] ={12,0x0001},
    ['4'] ={13,0x0000}, ['$'] ={13,0x0001},
    ['5'] ={14,0x0000}, ['%'] ={14,0x0001},
    ['6'] ={15,0x0000}, ['^'] ={15,0x0001},
    ['7'] ={16,0x0000}, ['&'] ={16,0x0001},
    ['8'] ={17,0x0000}, ['*'] ={17,0x0001},
    ['9'] ={18,0x0000}, ['('] ={18,0x0001},
    ['0'] ={19,0x0000}, [')'] ={19,0x0001},
    ['-'] ={20,0x0000}, ['_'] ={20,0x0001},
    ['='] ={21,0x0000}, ['+'] ={21,0x0001},
    ['q'] ={24,0x0000}, ['Q'] ={24,0x0001},
    ['w'] ={25,0x0000}, ['W'] ={25,0x0001},
    ['e'] ={26,0x0000}, ['E'] ={26,0x0001},
    ['r'] ={27,0x0000}, ['R'] ={27,0x0001},
    ['t'] ={28,0x0000}, ['T'] ={28,0x0001},
    ['y'] ={29,0x0000}, ['Y'] ={29,0x0001},
    ['u'] ={30,0x0000}, ['U'] ={30,0x0001},
    ['i'] ={31,0x0000}, ['I'] ={31,0x0001},
    ['o'] ={32,0x0000}, ['O'] ={32,0x0001},
    ['p'] ={33,0x0000}, ['P'] ={33,0x0001},
    ['['] ={34,0x0000}, ['{'] ={34,0x0001},
    [']'] ={35,0x0000}, ['}'] ={35,0x0001},
    ['\n']={36,0x0000},
    ['a'] ={38,0x0000}, ['A'] ={38,0x0001},
    ['s'] ={39,0x0000}, ['S'] ={39,0x0001},
    ['d'] ={40,0x0000}, ['D'] ={40,0x0001},
    ['f'] ={41,0x0000}, ['F'] ={41,0x0001},
    ['g'] ={42,0x0000}, ['G'] ={42,0x0001},
    ['h'] ={43,0x0000}, ['H'] ={43,0x0001},
    ['j'] ={44,0x0000}, ['J'] ={44,0x0001},
    ['k'] ={45,0x0000}, ['K'] ={45,0x0001},
    ['l'] ={46,0x0000}, ['L'] ={46,0x0001},
    [';'] ={47,0x0000}, [':'] ={47,0x0001},
    ['\'']={48,0x0000}, ['"'] ={48,0x0001},
    ['`'] ={49,0x0000}, ['~'] ={49,0x0001},
    ['?'] ={51,0x0000}, ['|'] ={51,0x0001},
    ['z'] ={52,0x0000}, ['Z'] ={52,0x0001},
    ['x'] ={53,0x0000}, ['X'] ={53,0x0001},
    ['c'] ={54,0x0000}, ['C'] ={54,0x0001},
    ['v'] ={55,0x0000}, ['V'] ={55,0x0001},
    ['b'] ={56,0x0000}, ['B'] ={56,0x0001},
    ['n'] ={57,0x0000}, ['N'] ={57,0x0001},
    ['m'] ={58,0x0000}, ['M'] ={58,0x0001},
    [','] ={59,0x0000}, ['<'] ={59,0x0001},
    ['.'] ={60,0x0000}, ['>'] ={60,0x0001},
    ['/'] ={61,0x0000}, ['\\']={61,0x0001},
    [' '] ={65,0x000},
};
```

And then you call it like:

```
i64   bdim = 2;
char* data = "hi";
fori(i, 0,bdim){
    x11_key_t key = X11_ASCII_TO_KEY[data[i]];
    printf("%02x %04x\n", key.code, key.state);
}
```

You can also implement it programatically, using the output from `xcb_get_keyboard_mapping_unchecked()` and `xcb_get_modifier_mapping_unchecked()`.