# X11/Xlib c/c++ char to XKeyEvent keycode

Tags: c++, c, x11, xlib

My need is to convert a char into a keycode to send an event with `XSendEvent`.

I'm using `XStringToKeysym("a")`, but when I use chars like `:` I get an invalid result.

Is it possible to bypass use of keysym and convert char directly to `XKeyEvent` keycode?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is something wrong with `XKeysymToKeycode()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the Unicode representation of the character and prepend `U` to it. For instance, in case of `:` these would do the same thing:

```
XStringToKeysym("colon")
XStringToKeysym("U003A")
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do better than @Artyom's answer. If you look at `<X11/keysymdef.h>` you find that for `ASCII` 0x20-0xFF, the characters map *directly* to `XKeySyms`. So, I'd say it's simpler to just use that range of characters directly as `KeyCodes`, and just map the remaining 32 characters.

For a more detailed answer including example code, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771958/3149905

Answer (score 0):

`XStringToKeysym` converts a name to a keysym, so `":"` won't work, you have to use `"colon"` instead.

Keycodes are not standard (keyboard layouts vary), hence keysyms are used and are defined in `<X11/keysymdef.h>`.

The best you can do, is to use `XKeysymToKeycode` with XK_a and XK_colon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but my problem is that I don't know which char I have to convert. Infact I have to send a complete string, like "http://www.google.it/"

Comment: I think you'll have to make a look up table, character to key sym, maybe do a-z with XStringToKeysym but lookup the punctuation